# Image Swipe from left to right and right to left in android?

Tags: android

I want to swipe image from left to right and right to left with finger based on three positions i want to change image.if i move from Both to left then circle should show on at Male and if i move directly from male to female then circle should be at female position. i have tried with toggle button but it will work only for two images.

see below is scenario

Male--->Both--->Female

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you know that there are only three items: 0 for men, 1 for both, 2 for female. Take a variable e.g. counter=0. When value of counter becomes 2 then reset its value to 0 and when its value becomes 0, then reset it to 2. That's the logic.

Comment: thanks for your logic. but how do we know image is moved to that position? how can i move image to left or right?

Comment: Place your images in array. 
int[] images={R.drawable.man,R.drawable.both,R.drawable.female}; 
Now they will have fix position.